# Error message "invalid escape sequence near "\%" when tex.sprint is inside a \chapter command

Tags: luatex, chapters, luacode

The error message "invalid escape sequence near "\%"" occurs only when a \luaexec tex.sprint is placed inside a \chapter command: why ?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\def\CalculusResult{
\luaexec{Calculus = 1/3 tex.sprint (string.format("\%0.5f", Calculus))}}%

\chapter{\huge When placed inside a chapter command, the  CalculusResult \CalculusResult ~  prints well but produces an error message: invalid escape sequence near "\%" }% 

\huge No error message if the CalculusResult \CalculusResult ~ is in the text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The command is not robust, use `\protect\CalculusResult`, or define it with \DeclareRobustCommand or \NewDocumentCommand (from xparse package).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not much different from things like `\chapter{abc \eqref{def}}` (`\eqref` is one of the few fragile commands).

The macro `\luaexec` is fragile, so it should be protected; burying it into another command is not sufficient, unless the other command is protected.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand\CalculusResult{%
  \luaexec{Calculus = 1/3 tex.sprint (string.format("\%0.5f", Calculus))}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{When placed inside a chapter command, the
  CalculusResult \protect\CalculusResult{} prints
  well but produces an error message: invalid escape sequence near "\%"}

No error message if the CalculusResult \CalculusResult{} is in the text.

\end{document}
```

Note that I have used `%` in the correct places. You had two in useless ones and missed one in an important place.